# Passing JSON to AJAX PHP can not access the $_REQUEST[VARIABLE]

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress

here is the AJAX REQUEST

http://www.sample.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_ajax&brim=val@val.com&email=&fn=send_email_feedback&human={"id":78,"nkey":610}&message=type&type=1

in the human={"id":78,"nkey":610}

when receiving and assigning it to a variable in php via

$human = $_REQUEST['human']

$human->id     <--------- HAS NO VALUE

Answer (score 2):

On your $http request, have you change parameters like this :

```
$http({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {'human': Object.toJSON({
    // DATA
  })},
  transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
  },
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$human = json_decode(str_replace("\\",'', $_REQUEST['human'])); // this may work
echo $human->id;
```

or
    echo $human['id'];

Comment: tried json_decode before it doesnt work, additional info when I echo $_REQUEST['human'] it results to    {\"id\":78,\"nkey\":610}